# what is there a need of different ports 9001 and 50070 for namenode?

Tags: hadoop, ports

the 50070 port is the webui port for the namenode .then what is the purpose served by the 9001 port. When datanode connects with the namenode which port is used ?and when does 50070 port functions ?

Answer (score 0):

Port 50070 is usually used for HDFS UIs whereas port 9001 is usually for M/R task trackers. See [Cloudera Default Ports Quick Reference](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/)

Answer (score 0):

`50070` is the `default Web UI` port number for namenode . while 8020/9000 is the Internal Process Communicator port (IPC) for namenode

for more info [Hadoop default ports](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/)